# Removing "blank" or bad rows in a csv file using Perl.

Tags: sql-server, perl, t-sql

I am working on a project that exports .csv files from a really old application (a DOS base application). The export works, but it truncates a column (it seems at random) and inserts it into the next line. It's usually the last half of a word or something of that sort. What I would like to know, if there is a way to use Perl to remove those lines. I currently use a Perl Script to remove all comma delimiters and replace them with the pipe (|) delimiter. I found using the pipe makes it easier to insert into SQL to use. I'm very, very new to Perl but this code works perfectly to replace the comma's with the pipe. Is there a way to use this and remove the "bad" rows. I have tried importing into SQL with bulk insert, but receive errors such as "Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 49, column 17." I have looked at the export and these errors are occurring where there is a full column with all 17 rows, but the next line is just a |cial) or |3. I hope I made this clear. Thank you for the help.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $in_file = "Deal_Log.csv";
my $out_file = "NewDeal.csv";

open my $fh, '<', $in_file or die "$in_file: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $out_file or die "$out_file: $!";

my $in_csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;
my $out_csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { sep_char => '|', eol => "\n" } );

while( my $row = $in_csv->getline( $fh ) ) { 
    $out_csv->print( $out_fh, $row );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not output the line immediatelly. Instead, read in the next line and check the number of columns. If there are all 17, output the previous line, otherwise append the line to the previous remembered line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $in_file  = 'Deal_Log.csv';
my $out_file = 'NewDeal.csv';
my $size     = 17;

open my $fh,     '<', $in_file  or die "$in_file: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $out_file or die "$out_file: $!";

my $in_csv  = 'Text::CSV_XS'->new;
my $out_csv = 'Text::CSV_XS'->new( { sep_char => '|',
                                     eol      => "\n",
                                   } );

my $previous = [];
while( my $row = $in_csv->getline($fh) ) {
    if (@$row == $size) {
        $out_csv->print($out_fh, $previous) if @$previous;
        $previous = $row;
    } else {
        $previous->[-1] .= $row->[0];
    }
}
$out_csv->print($out_fh, $previous);  # Do not forget to print the last remembered line.
```

Comment: Would you have an example of doing this? When I say I'm very, very new to Perl, I mean I just started using Perl last week. But this is a nice tip! Thank you.

Comment: You're the man! So far that is working like a charm! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem with Text::CSV_XS. Several "random" lines were truncated and merged with the next line. In the truncated lines some content was actually lost and field separators as well as line separators were missing.

Accepting the performance penalty I resorted to Text::CSV_PP and the problems were gone. I suggest you try Text::CSV_PP if your CSV-creation isn't time critical, because with large files it's definitely slower.